# select all elements in an array that fall between 2 specific elements 

Tags: php, arrays

I have a normal, boring old array which has a lot of data in it. Let's say the array is structured like this:

`$myArray = array( 'a','b','c','START','d','e','f','END' );`

Now, I need to select only the values that come after START, but before END. So, in this example, I need to select the values 'd', 'e', and 'f'.

Here's the tricky part; START will always exist, however END may or may not (this is how the data is returned from the server). If START and END both exist, then I just need the values inbetween the 2. if only START exists, then just select all the values from START until the end of the array. 'START' does not have a fixed index; its location changes depending on the data supplied from the server.

So what would be quick, relatively painless way to rip out these values in between 2 specified values, and then save them to a new array?

EDIT: The only implementation I was able to get functioning was the one provided by @nickb, further down in the comments. I have added it to this OP for ease of use for others.

```
array_shift( $array[0]); // Get rid of the 'count' element
$start = array_search( 'registered:current', $array[0], true);
$end = array_search( 'END', $array[0], true); // Change 'END' to whatever it is
$return = array_slice( $array[0], $start + 1, ($end ? ($end - $start - 1) : null));
```

Comment: Take the index returned from [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Comment: You'd enjoy programming much better if you used interesting, new arrays.

Comment: Use my answer. And don't forget to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle (KISS principle). My code is the fastest you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$end = array_search( 'END', $array, true);
$return = array_slice( $array,
    array_search( 'START', $array, true) + 1,
        ($end ? ($end - count( $array)) : null)
);
```

If `'END'` isn't found, `array_search()` will return false, which causes the the 3rd parameter to `array_slice()` to be set to `null`, returning the remaining elements in the array, starting at `'START'`. But if `'END'` is found, you'll get an array containing the elements between `'START'` and `'END'`, as seen in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/BDHvDT).

**Edit:** Here is a simpler implementation that uses the indexes directly, which is based on Matt's edit with some tweaks to make it not include the delimiter:

```
$start = array_search( 'START', $array, true) + 1; // +1 to get rid of 'START'
$end = array_search( 'END', $array, true);
$return = array_slice( $array, $start, ($end ? ($end - $start - 1) : null)); // Omit 3rd param if 'END' is not found
```

**Edit:** Final implementation:

```
array_shift( $array[0]); // Get rid of the 'count' element
$start = array_search( 'registered:current', $array[0], true);
$end = array_search( 'END', $array[0], true); // Change 'END' to whatever it is
$return = array_slice( $array[0], $start + 1, ($end ? ($end - $start - 1) : null));
```

Comment: <strike>You're already omitting the third parameter.</strike> apparently not

Comment: Wouldn't `null` be equivalent to omitting the third parameter?

Comment: Well you don't want to omit the third parameter unless `'END'` isn't in the array, which is what I meant.

Comment: @nickb I understand that, but passing `false` won't "omit" the third parameter; passing `null` will.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I feel like this is what I need to do, however when I try it on my test app, $return is not getting populated.. It just says array(0) { } on a vardump. Any ideas? **EDIT** trying out the most recent edit

Comment: @Prefix - Please try again, I've updated my sample quite a bit and added a demo to show that it is working.

Comment: what happens when `'END'` comes before `'START'` though? :)

Comment: @Jack - But that would violate Newton's 4th law, and life as we know it would cease to exist!

Comment: @nickb, thanks for your help, however the array is still not getting populated. Here is a `var_dump()` of a small part of the actual array im using.. http://pastebin.com/1AJzA5fE

Comment: @Prefix - And to make it work with my code, you've replaced `$array` with `$yourArray[0]['count'];`, and `'START'` with `'registered:current'`, correct?

Comment: @nickb of course :) (I may be bad at programming but I'm not *THAT* bad, haha!)

Comment: @Prefix - To make this easier, can you post a pastebin of `var_export( $yourArray);` ?

Comment: @Prefix - I was being dumb when I saw your original pastebin output - `$array[0]['count']` is an int, not an array. I've updated my answer with your sample array and you can [see in this demo](http://viper-7.com/4hMbuM) that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Take the index returned from [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). Try this:

```
$startIndex = array_search("START", $myArray);
$endIndex = array_search("END", $myArray);
if ($endIndex === false) {
    $endIndex = count($myArray) - 1;
}

$newArray = array();

for($i = $startIndex; $i < $endIndex; $i++) {
    // do your thing
    $newArray[] = $myArray[$i];
}
```

**UPDATE:** could use `array_slice()` in lieu of looping.

```
$newArray = array_slice($myArray, $startIndex, $endIndex - $startIndex);
```

Comment: I agree- Somebody is going crazy with the down votes on the answers to this question.

Comment: @Matt no frigging idea! For some reason all my questions and question answers seem to get ridiculously downvoted..I upvoted you, thank you for the input. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Prefix Anytime...I'm not going to get my panties in a bunch because I lost 4 rep points; it's just annoying when people down-vote and *don't* give a reason (or +1 someone else's reason). That doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array( 'a','b','c','START','d','e','f','END' );

$arr = array();
$start = false;
foreach($myArray as $val) {
   if($val == 'END') {
       break;
   }

   if($start) {
       $arr[] = $val;
   }

   if($val == 'START') {
       $start = true;
   }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: People are playing with downvote. I hope they are not those who answer this question.

Comment: I believe someone went a little crazy with the downvoting. We are in this community to try and help, down voting when someone is trying to help is very rude.  IF they are being polite and reasonable. Ignore the answer is sufficient.

Comment: Hi Kasp3r, I haven't tried your solution just yet but I hate all the overly angsty downvoters on this site. For the record, I've upvoted everyone in here simply for trying to help me out. Thank you!

Comment: @kasp3r: I've tried your method, I like it because it's very simple / to the point, however my $arr doesn't seem to be getting populated.. Here is a sample of the array I am using if it's any help http://pastebin.com/m59YrdhH

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($myArray as $A){
    if(//condition of the elements you want to display){

      }
}
```

It would be easier to be helpful if we knew exactly how your array was structured.

Comment: This is very vague compared to other answers, and does not give any information that wasn't already known. The array structure is given.

Comment: I... Did give the array structure... o.o

Comment: Holy cow community chill. I read the question Rude-Matt. It was delivered in such a way that suggested it was a very hypothetical structure, Maybe the actual array was associative or something.

Comment: The array was hypothetical because if I posted the actual array, there are hundreds of entries. I posted it how it is in the OP for ease of communication. sorry if it caused any trouble. :)

Comment: I was just unsure if you were giving an exact miniature version, e.g. same format(string elements, non-associative, non-multi-dimensional)
The array_slice people have suggested is probably the best answer given. In my widely despised answer, it is a way to do it while checking if an element is a more specific value, for example not in a row in the array from start to end. But all elements where X = Y. For example.